# Adapter NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I have my Adapter and I read the values in a document XML. The ArrayList.size() is = 3. When a run the App, the error is java.lang.NullPointerException.

The class object I think than is all ok.

Thanks!

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        ArrayList<datos_correos> arraydir = new ArrayList<datos_correos>();
        datos_correos mensaje;

        mensaje = new datos_correos("23 de Noviembre de 2014", "jordikid", "Lala", "Zokola", "Asunto");
        arraydir.add(mensaje);

        for(PostValue post : helper.posts) {

            mensaje = new datos_correos(post.getCorreo_fecha(), post.getCorreo_de(), post.getCorreo_mensaje(), post.getCorreo_destinatario(), post.getCorreo_asunto());
            arraydir.add(mensaje);
        }

        adapter_correos(arraydir);

        pd.dismiss();
    }

}

private void adapter_correos(ArrayList<datos_correos> arraydir){

    System.out.println("dentro adapter correos: ");
    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listado_correos);
    datos_correos mensaje;

    System.out.println("Numero de elementos en el array: "+arraydir.size());

    mensaje = new datos_correos("23 de Noviembre de 2014", "jordikid", "Lala", "Zokola", "Asunto");
    arraydir.add(mensaje);

    final Adapter_bandejaEntrada adapter = new Adapter_bandejaEntrada(bandeja_entrada.this, arraydir);

    ****Line 153**** lista.setAdapter(adapter);


}


public class XMLMensajes extends DefaultHandler {

    String TAG = "XMLHelper";

    Boolean currTag = false;
    String currTagVal = "";
    public PostValue post = null;
    public ArrayList<PostValue> posts = new ArrayList<PostValue>();

    public void get(String s) {
        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader();
            mXmlReader.setContentHandler(this);

            InputStream mInputStream = new URL(s).openStream();
            mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        if(currTag) {
            currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
            currTag = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        currTag = false;

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("fecha")) {
            post.setCorreo_fecha(currTagVal);
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("mensaje")) {
            post.setCorreo_mensaje(currTagVal);
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("asunto")) {
            post.setCorreo_asunto(currTagVal);
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("destinatario")) {
            post.setCorreo_destinatario(currTagVal);
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("de")) {
            post.setCorreo_destinatario(currTagVal);
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            post.setCorreo_id(currTagVal);
        }
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("correo")) {
            posts.add(post);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                             Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        Log.i(TAG, "TAG: " + localName);

        currTag = true;
        currTagVal = "";
        if(localName.equals("correo"))
            post = new PostValue();
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
Process: com.padaleamos.app, PID: 1168
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.padaleamos.app.bandeja_entrada.adapter_correos(bandeja_entrada.java:153)
            at com.padaleamos.app.bandeja_entrada.access$000(bandeja_entrada.java:24)
            at com.padaleamos.app.bandeja_entrada$PostAsync.onPostExecute(bandeja_entrada.java:126)
            at com.padaleamos.app.bandeja_entrada$PostAsync.onPostExecute(bandeja_entrada.java:71)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hi Jordi, please add the exception from the logcat.

Comment: Please provide more data. Show your StackTrace

Comment: Also, show where you declare `helper` and `pd`

Comment: added the logcat and code helper

Comment: As your exception indicates line 153 but your code snippets do not have line numbers, it would make sense to mark the relevant lines from the stack trace in the code snippets. Help us help you.

Comment: The line 153 is lista.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: `lista` is null , because you shouldn't use findviewbyid in adapter , You should use view.findviewbyid instead.